# table relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I currently have a Product model and a Question model.

I have originally developed an application and in this application I had this relationship between them:

> Product has_many :questions Question
>   belongs_to :product

However, I know now that a Question doesn't always have to belong to a Product.

What kind of relationship or solution should I be doing for something like this?

*Note: I am using Rails 2.3.8*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question, I don't see any problem with what you have. The Question records that do not belong to a Product will simply have a product_id column set to null.

There could be an issue if you have a validation in your Question model that checks the presence of a product_id but if that's the case, simply remove the validation on product_id.

You may also want to check that there is no constraint at the database level that prevents the product_id foreign key from being null.

Comment: Well, I never knew that. I always thought that a question would fail if it isn't related to a product. thank you for clearing that for me.